# Move mailbox from 2003 to 2010 fails due to read receipts in mailbox

Tags: exchange-2010

We have a user who errors out when migrating to 2010 for all REPORT.IPM.Note.IPNRN messages (read receipt)

One sample is below.  Does anyone know how I can address this?

```
 Operation: ISourceMailbox.ExportMessages

OperationSide: Source

Primary (5851b21f-5751-4445-b108-f80ca52676c7)

Flags: None

PropTags: (null)</errorContext>

</baditem>

11/10/2011 9:51:22 PM [NYCEXHC02] Stage: CopyingMessages. Percent complete: 26.

11/10/2011 9:51:22 PM [NYCEXHC02] Copy progress: 4638/54364 messages, 70.67 MB (74,103,365 bytes)/2.794 GB (3,000,506,580 bytes).

11/10/2011 9:52:04 PM [NYCEXHC02] A corrupted item was encountered during the move operation. The item wasn't copied to the destination mailbox.

<baditem errorType="MapiExceptionPartialCompletion" errorCode="0x80070680" flags="0x00000000" id="000000008A50650BD7724C4DA882F20A1BF1CCDC0700438AD32CEE763542AA533A80C5F741B800001AD300020000438AD32CEE763542AA533A80C5F741B800001DF2F0FE0000">

  <folder id="000000008A50650BD7724C4DA882F20A1BF1CCDC0100438AD32CEE763542AA533A80C5F741B800001AD300020000">W B Moore - August</folder>

  <sender>Linda  </sender>

  <recipient> , Jackie</recipient>

  <subject>Read:  final Reimbursements and concerns</subject>

  <messageClass>REPORT.IPM.Note.IPNRN</messageClass>

  <size>2305</size>

  <dateSent>02/25/2009 22:26:18</dateSent>

  <dateReceived>02/25/2009 22:27:08</dateReceived>

  <errorMessage>MapiExceptionPartialCompletion: Unable to copy message(s). (hr=0x40680, ec=0)

Diagnostic context:

    Lid: 45095   EMSMDB.EcDoRpcExt2 called [length=78]

    Lid: 61479   EMSMDB.EcDoRpcExt2 returned [ec=0x0][length=128][latency=0]

    Lid: 23226   --- ROP Parse Start ---

    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropFXSrcCopyMessages [75]

    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropTellVersion [134]

    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropFXSrcGetBuffer [78]

    Lid: 31418   --- ROP Parse Done ---

    Lid: 21686   StoreEc: 0x471     

    Lid: 22710   StoreEc: 0x471     

    Lid: 22550  

    Lid: 21706   StoreEc: 0x471     

    Lid: 27126  

    Lid: 18634   StoreEc: 0x471     

    Lid: 28022  

    Lid: 25290   StoreEc: 0x40680   

    Lid: 45095   EMSMDB.EcDoRpcExt2 called [length=45]

    Lid: 61479   EMSMDB.EcDoRpcExt2 returned [ec=0x0][length=42][latency=0]

    Lid: 23226   --- ROP Parse Start ---

    Lid: 31418   --- ROP Parse Done ---

    Lid: 16465  

    Lid: 24657   StoreEc: 0x40680   </errorMessage>

  <errorContext>--------

Operation: LocalSourceFolder.CopyBatch

EntryIDs: [[len=70, data=000000008A50650BD7724C4DA882F20A1BF1CCDC0700438AD32CEE763542AA533A80C5F741B800001AD300020000438AD32CEE763542AA533A80C5F741B800001DF2F0FE0000]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, these may be older read receipts and so forth which, for whatever reason (corruption), may not come over - Rowell is right - basically, you only can choose to 'ignore' these corrupted items which, in most cases, may be okay.

BUT, if you want to capture those details of what was "not" transferred (corrupted items), 

1) Make sure you set a high enough "corrupted message limit" as Rowell specified above
   so the mailbox gets transferred, despite those corrupt read receipts.

2) After mailbox is 100% transferred, Click on "Move Requests"

3) Highlight the specific mailbox move request, right-click, choose "Properties"

4) Click the "Log" tab, 

5) Click "View," (which will open the entire detailed log for that Move Request),

6) Click "Ctrl-C" (which places the entire log in your paste buffer)

7) Open Notepad or equivalent, and save that to a file, with the user's name - something like "Anthony-Smith-corrupted-read-receipts-Jan2012.txt"

Note: I have seen an average of 20 of these corrupted receipts for maibloxes of size 3GB and higher (yes, we actually have a few users with greather-than 3GB mailboxes; in some cases, for those, we create for them their own Mailbox DBs, when they reach a certain limit).

As you look through the log, you will notice that it contains all the pertinent details for the corrupted items, in case a future audit requires that info.

The log detail contains Sender, Recipient, Subject (example: "Read: Updated Conference" - so the Subject, in effect, contains the 'status' of the read receipt), Date Sent, and Date Received (among other info).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the message may have been corrupted. When you migrate the user's mailbox try selecting to skip the corrupted messages (if this is possible for your organization) under the Move Settings of a Move Request. You can specify how many corrupted messages to skip.

The reason why you would skip the corrupt messages is because the default action is to skip the mailbox.

[image: Skip the corrupted messages]

Comment: What if I think the corrupt item is valuable, and I don't want to loose it?

Comment: If the messages are truly corrupt I don't see a reason to keep it since it isn't valuable at that point. Another thing to check, is your send receive limits the same in 2003 and 2010? If 2003 has a lower send receive limit than 2010 that may cause a corrupt message.